# While using dual monitor(extended screen) Application UI comes on wrong screen

Tags: java, windows

I work on a java application . When I tried to connect an external monitor to my laptop (to use it in extend screen mode) and tried to run the application from the extended monitor it still opens the application on my laptop window and not on the extended window. I am not really sure if I need to add a java code for this or is it something to do with Windows options. Basically everything , the error popups and everything come on the laptop window and not on the extended screen . Is there a way out to ensure the application and its popups come on the correct screen?

Answer (score 0):

The position of windows on the monitors can be set by code.
If you use two monitors with extended desktop, you have to use positions, that match the second monitor.

Simple example:
You have two monitors, each with a resolution of 100x100 (for the sake of demonstration).
If you use the extended desktop, your desktop is of 200x100.
You need to set the windows x coordinate to be above 100 to be on the second monitor.

But be aware: If you switch back to only one monitor, the window will still be places at e.g. 150 and will be offscreen then.